# Какой размер у пикселя

Tags: вёрстка

В консоли google chrome можно выставить требуемый размер экрана устройства для оптимизации размещения элементов сайта. Ширина и высота выставляется в пикселях. 
Если учитывать тот факт, что от разрешения меняется размер пикселей {количество на дюйм}, то какое разрешение использует Гугл в своей панели

Comment: Разрешение и есть количество пикселей, поэтому оно никак не меняется. Если в консоли хрома выставлено разрешение 1024 на 768, то оно и будет таким. То, что может меняться, это DPI и оно имеет место быть, только если вы меряете в дюймах ваш макет.